# Configure Home/End key to move to start/end of line in IntelliJ

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I know ctrl+right/ctrl+left will do that, but I am used to pressing Home/End and it's frustrating when it doesn't do it in IntelliJ. I use [KeyRemap4Macbook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) which works great for terminal and elsewhere with the Home/End key setting, but the settings for some reason do not work in IntelliJ.

I am on MAC OSX, IJ 12.1.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are 2 settings in KeyRemap4MacBook:

[image]

Unchecking the first option, and keeping the 2nd checked allowed me to use Home/End in IJ.

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ IDEA doesn't seem to support ⌃A and ⌃E but it does support ⌘← and ⌘→. You could use this setting instead:

[image]

Or add something like this to [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en):

```
<appdef>
  <appname>INTELLIJ</appname>
  <equal>com.jetbrains.intellij.ce</equal>
</appdef>
<item>
  <name>test</name>
  <identifier>test</identifier>
  <block>
    <only>INTELLIJ</only>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::HOME, ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::END, ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::HOME, VK_SHIFT | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::END, VK_SHIFT | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L</autogen>
  </block>
  <block>
    <not>INTELLIJ</not>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::HOME, ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::A, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::END, ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::E, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::HOME, VK_SHIFT | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::A, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::END, VK_SHIFT | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::E, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L</autogen>
  </block>
</item>
```

You can see the source of the predefined settings from https://raw.github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml.

Comment: Hi Lauri, I used the exact setting in KeyRemap4Macbook as u posted the screenshot of, it DOES NOT change home to cmd+left in IntelliJ. It does it elsewhere. Where is the private.xml file? I couldn't find it in IntelliJ's package contents..

Comment: It worked for me with both the community edition and ultimate edition. `private.xml` is in `~/Library/Application Support/KeyRemap4MacBook/` (see the link).

Comment: That xml snippet didn't work, but I got it to work somehow else. I posted it below. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Did you include the `<?xml version="1.0"?>` and `<root>` elements, or did you enable the setting in KeyRemap4MacBook.app?

Comment: It already had:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
</root>
I added the snippet after it.

Answer (score 0):

Update oct 2022: KeyRemap4MacBook is now Karabiner Elements.

1. Install Karabiner Elements.
2. Import the `Home and End` `complex modification` from [Karabiner Elements Complex Modifications](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/?q=home%20and%20end)
3. Enable the newly imported rule if enable option was not given/selected.

tested on karabiner elements 14.10

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).